# Distributed File System using NFS?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, distributed-computing

Is it possible to setup NFS to perform as a parallel distributed file system? I'd like to have to NFS servers containing the same file data and serving file ops request for load balancing and to eliminate single point of failure.

I've setup single NFS instances but never parallel.

If not with NFS - is there another system out there that will do this without a lot of fuss and with production-quality reliability?

I'm running CentOS5 on all of my servers.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off to set up a rolling X day backup and a Raid 10 or Raid 5 for the file server? This way your people are only accessing the data in one place (prevent version conflicts) and is redundant in case of hardware failure. If the entire RAID is hosed then you still have your rolling X day backups.

Comment: If you're worried about throughput, you could Bond/Team two similar nics together for increased bandwidth.

Comment: I assume you've already looked at GlusterFS?

Comment: +1 for GlusterFS.  Not used it but quite impressed by a user story I heard at OSCON last week

Comment: I'll take a look at GlusterFS. Had not heard of it before. I'm looking at this for web servers that can take a pounding randomly, but for short bursts. I was hoping to develop both redundancy in case of hardware failure, and load balancing to handle peak loads.

Comment: Nics are already bonded on the hardware. The NFS hosts would be Xen virtual guests on separate machines.

Answer (score 1):

I have had excellent experiences using [AFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System) with distributed read-only replicas.  It is, however, a great deal of fuss.